# Rails select options not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

I want to create a search form for products according to category and sub-category. The user will have to select a category first and then a sub-category. The code that I have written is below:

```
<%= form_tag('/products/search') do |f| %>
<%=  select_tag(:category_id, Category.all.collect { |s| [ s.name, s.id ]} ) %>
<%=  select_tag(:subcategory_id, Subcategory.all.collect { |s| [ s.name, s.id ]} ) %>
  <div><%= submit_tag 'Search' %></div>
<% end %>
```

but when I see the page in the browser, I see empty selects. The HTML source returns select with no options as below:

```
<select id="category_id" name="category_id">
 jewellery1beads2pendants3</select>
<select id="subcategory_id" name="subcategory_id">necklace1earrings2taps3</select>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this.

```
 <%=  select_tag(:category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, "id", "name")) %>
```

Comment: oh yeh.. may have missed that.. sorry :)